# Move sidebar under header

Tags: css

It's been two days since I started trying to make this work and I swear I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
This is my HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
Home
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

And this is the CSS

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

div#header {
position:fixed;
outline: none;
text-align:center;
font-family:'Arvo', serif;
color:white;
font-size:48px;
height:5%;
width:100%;
background-color: rgba(0,79,113,1);
}

div#sidebar {
position:relative;
bottom
font-family:'Arvo', serif;
list-style-type: square;
list-style-position: inside;
color:white;
height:100%;
width:5%;
background-color: rgba(100,147,167,1);
}

li{
font-family:'Arvo', serif;
}
```

I'm a complete CSS noob(my code is probably horrible) and I would want the sidebar under the header bar, and the text in the middle of the sidebar aligned to the right. Can someone help?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k5ffLzoe/

Comment: can you add images of what you expect?

Comment: For one thing you're missing a closing `</div>` after the end of your `<ul>`

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://codepen.io/mattpark22/pen/xVxxWe

I've fixed a missing  closing tag, and updated your CSS for you.

HTML:

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

div#header {
outline: none;
text-align:center;
font-family:'Arvo', serif;
color:white;
font-size:48px;
height:5%;
width:100%;
background-color: rgba(0,79,113,1);
}

div#sidebar {
float: right;
text-align: center;
font-family:'Arvo', serif;
list-style-type: square;
list-style-position: inside;
color:white;
height:100%;
width:5%;
background-color: rgba(100,147,167,1);
}

li{
font-family:'Arvo', serif;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
Home
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm just beginning with CSS and you helped a lot! The only thing is that now the sidebar isn't as long as the screen even though I set height to 100%

Comment: If your only supporting IE10+, then you could look at CSS3 Flexbox for achieving the height, an example can be found here: http://codepen.io/berkin/pen/vFCwn

However Flexbox doesn't work in IE9 and IE8 though.

Comment: I don't particularly care about compatibility right now as this is just for school and I'm just starting with Webpage coding so I'm gonna use that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've adde the following css to give you what might be closer to what you are looking for

```
 /**ADDED**/
 div#header {
   height: 10%;
 }
 div#sidebar {
   width: 10%;
   position: relative;
   top: 55px;
 }
 ul {
   width: 50px;
 }
```

You can see results here: https://jsfiddle.net/ec5p7pxq/

Good practice is to use class instead of id for css